# How to overwrite columns in pandas DataFrames of using other as existed category

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Here's my dataset

```
No   Item             Desc
1    AWS              Lambda
2    AWS              Polly
3    Microsoft        Azure
4    Microsoft        Excel
5    Google           BigQuery
6    RDS              Database
7    Athena           Big Data
8    Lambda           NoSQL
```

Here's What I want is make any other item than `AWS`, `Google`, and `Microsoft` as `AWS`

```
No   Item             Desc
1    AWS              Lambda
2    AWS              Polly
3    Microsoft        Azure
4    Microsoft        Excel
5    Google           BigQuery
6    AWS              Database
7    AWS              Big Data
8    AWS              NoSQL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df['Item'] = np.where(df['Item'].isin(['Microsoft','Google']), df['Item'], 'AWS')
#alternative
#df['Item'] = np.where(np.in1d(df['Item'], ['Microsoft','Google']), df['Item'], 'AWS')
```

Or:

```
df.loc[~df['Item'].isin(['Microsoft','Google']), 'Item'] = 'AWS'
```

---

```
print (df)
   No       Item      Desc
0   1        AWS    Lambda
1   2        AWS     Polly
2   3  Microsoft     Azure
3   4  Microsoft     Excel
4   5     Google  BigQuery
5   6        AWS  Database
6   7        AWS  Big Data
7   8        AWS     NoSQL
```

Comment: I not guess that the second solution will be that simple